# NodeJs MongoDB and Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

While deploying a `Node` application to `Heroku` I'm receiving the following error message. Any ideas what might cause it?

> 1. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497018+00:00 app[web.1]:   "stack": [
> 2. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497020+00:00 app[web.1]:     "TypeError: options.mongooseConnection.once is not a function",
> 3. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497021+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at MongoStore (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:91:48)",
> 4. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497021+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Object. (/app/app/session/index.js:14:17)",
> 5. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497022+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)",
> 6. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497022+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)",
> 7. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497023+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)",
> 8. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497023+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)",
> 9. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497024+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)",
> 10. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497024+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
> 11. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497025+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Object. (/app/app/index.js:16:15)",
> 12. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497025+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)",
> 13. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497026+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)",
> 14. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497027+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)",
> 15. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497027+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)",
> 16. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497028+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)",
> 17. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497028+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
> 18. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497029+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Object. (/app/server.js:4:17)",
> 19. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497029+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)",
> 20. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497030+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)",
> 21. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497030+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)",
> 22. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497031+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)",
> 23. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497032+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)",
> 24. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497032+00:00 app[web.1]:     "    at startup (node.js:148:18)"
> 25. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497033+00:00 app[web.1]:   ],
> 26. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497033+00:00 app[web.1]:   "level": "error",
> 27. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497034+00:00 app[web.1]:   "message": "uncaughtException: options.mongooseConnection.once is not a function"
> 28. 2016-09-19T09:44:06.497035+00:00 app[web.1]: }

Comment: Can you put your `mongoose` connection code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating mongoose connection with `connect` not with `createConnection` method that's why you are getting this error.

> .createConnection() returns a Connection instance.
>
> .connect() returns the global mongoose instance.

Then if you want to use `once` method then you have to use `createConnection` method instead of `connect` method

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('MongoDB URL');
db.once('open', function() { ... });
```